# Windows boot loader on a Pen Drive (Chain-loader)

Tags: windows-7, bootloader, gpt

I want to convert my hard disk to GPT and install windows 7. Which is now giving an error while installing. What I am planning to do is,

1. Install the boot loader in MBR Partition of a Pen Drive.
2. Install the Windows 7 on the GPT partition of hard disk.
3. Insert the pen drive and do a usb-boot each time I want to turn on the system.

I've already done it for Linux OS (Ubuntu and Fedora) and I Know this can be done using `Grub`. But can it be possible without using `Grub`?

Comment: MBR and GPT are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Ramhound That's why I want to do a Chainloading from MBR to GPT.

Comment: Why?  Linux and Windows both support GPT.

Comment: @Ramhound I've seen it in pre-installed PCs but when I try to make a fresh install, It's showing an error like `a driver CD is missing`.